# Getting a multi-property item to display once in a pivot table per instance

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

So I'm trying to run a frequency analysis - how often does an item show up?

Items can show up in a few ways:

```
Type    Make    Color   Count
1        A      Blue      5
1        B      Blue      3
2        A      Red       5 
2        A      Green     5
3        B      Green     5
```

I'm trying to figure out how many colors show up as a frequency, and I want to know in each type how often it shows up at least once.

So for example:

Blue - It shows up in Type 1, in a Make A and a Make B. But I'd like to count in a make-agnostic way, so I'd only like to count the blue once.

Red - This one is easy, it only shows up once.

Green - This shows up in type 2 and in type 3 - I'd like to get "2" as my answer.

How can I "count" each time one of the items shows up, without double counting when it shows up twice? It's fairly easy to do with a straight formula - count all of them, then subtract out when I have both makes A and make B - but how can I get it to work on a pivot table?

Comment: Is the "Count" you have in your table, your expected output? Or is that unrelated?

Comment: The count is my expected output - I want to count how many times items show up, using a pivot table